# How to change Unity3d icon?

Tags: 16.04, icons, unity3d

I have Ubuntu 16.04 and Unity 3d installed (2018.1.0b13). I wanted to upgrade to this version because of the new features, but I'm experiencing an issue.I have installed Numix package, but Unity3d's icon is still in its orginal style.

[image]

I searched in Numix's folder and there is a .svg file with Unity3d's icon.Can you help me change this icon to look modern?

Thanks,
Matthew

Comment: Try another icon theme. Personally, I think this is best addressed a bug report with Numix team. Alternatively, you can see the .desktop file related to Unity3D and change the replacement icon name accordingly

Answer (score 0):

I did it this way:

1 - Create a `.desktop` file that links to the Unity3D installation.

2 - Change the `ICON` attribute in the `.desktop` file to point to Numix's icon ( or anything for that matter). For more robustness, you can set the value of `ICON` to `unity-editor-icon`.

for example in my case, the `Unity3D.desktop` file looks like this:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=Unity3D
Comment=Unity Game Engine
Exec=/home/behnam/Unity-2018.1.0f2/Editor/Unity
Icon=unity-editor-icon
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=Utility;Application;
Name[en_US]=Unity3D
```

3 - Add execution permissions to the `.desktop` file ( Otherwise, you won't be able to run it )

```
chmod +x Unity3D.desktop
```

4 - Put the file in the `~/.local/share/applications` directory

5 - Now you'll see it in the dash and the switcher with the good looking icon :)

[Unity3D Numix Icon in Dash](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N5kck.png)

[Unity3D Numix Icon in Switcher](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WpLUu.png)